# Visual Studio 2010 prompt says Could not prepare files for refactoring. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs, automated-refactoring

I work in a C# environment doing web development using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. Intellisense is still working and my code compiles and runs fine, but I cannot refactor my code using the right click menu refactor tool. I'm instead prompted, "Could not prepare files for refactoring." I already reset my settings to defaults but no luck. It's still not working. Other functions are working correctly like go to definition, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was due to Web Deployment Projects Beta. I needed to uninstall the beta for visual studio 2010 and install Web Deployment Projects RTW.

Comment: Go to Control Panel and uninstall WDP Beta. Optionally, reinstall RWT version of WDP.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Web Deployment Projects, I understand that deleting them fixes this (quite rare) issue.

Comment: Beta of Web Deployment Projects was the issue.